# How to pass data to table view by array?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, view

I want pass string to table view. In 1st, I can pass to table view but if I pass second string to table view will replace the data.  I pass data to table view like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [defaults stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
NomberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[NomberArray addObject:myString];

NSLog(@"nomber array = %@",NomberArray);
NSString *nomber = [NomberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.textLabel setText:nomber];
```

How do I pass more then 2 data to table view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably need to first read the [uitableview programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1). However, your problem seems to be related to populating the tableview. Here's an [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5) of how you do it.